# Container div not occupying full viewport height in the main app component html file for mobile devices in Angular 13 app

Tags: html, angular, sass, responsive-design

I am developing an app with Angular 13. It should have a responsive design and should work well in mobile devices. The code in app.component.html file is

```
<div class="app-header">
  <app-header></app-header>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code in app.component.scss file is

```
.app-header {
   min-width: 750px;
}

.main-container {
   min-height: 100vh;
   min-width: 600px;
   background-color: #f7f7f7;
   padding: 0px 75px 50px;
   .content {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 800px;
      min-width: 600px;
   }
}
```

The code in the header.component.html i.e app-header which is used in app-component is

```
<div class="header">
   <mat-toolbar>
   </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

The code in header.component.scss is

```
.header {
    .mat-toolbar {
        background: lightgreen;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
}
```

The reason I am following above approach is for my content inside the div with .content class to have minimum width of 600px and maximum width of 800px. This approach looks okay for desktop but for smaller devices the div with .main-container class doesn't occupy full viewport height as shown below.

[image]

Also I want header to occupy full screen width by setting width in percentage or viewport width like 100vw rather than using min-width: 750px. Even for .main-container div I added min-width: 600px and would like to replace it with 100vw or something similar. I want it to occupy full screen width irrespective of device. I tried but couldn't achieve the results I wanted. Please help me fix these issues.

Comment: Could you make a stackblitz exmaple of  your code? Could not reproduce

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing you want to rule out is a missing viewport meta tag in the header of your page.

Make sure you have a meta tag similar to this in the page header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Yes, I checked it. In Angular app, that tag is present in index.html file and it is there.

Comment: Thanks @suvenk. Using the HTML and SCSS you supplied, I was able to reproduce the issue you described if the viewport meta tag was omitted. A bit of a long shot, but make sure there's no caching issue that's complicating your troubleshooting as well. If you don't have any success, perhaps post a public example for us to look at.